# Can you get nuts that attach to regular screws?

Tags: screws, bolts

I have a screw attaching a plastic mould to a metal pole like so:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Obviously, the screw's thread size is not the same as a standard bolt thread size so a regular nut can't be attached to the end of the screw to hold it in place securely.  Can you get nuts that will attach to regular screws?  If not, is there some other kind of device I can use to somehow have the same effect as if this were a bolt with a nut attached to it and tightened on to the pole?

Comment: Does that screw go all the way through from the other side? Is that the screw that was provided by the manufacturer for the initial installation, or are you fixing this up yourself after parts failed/were lost/was purchased 2nd hand? A little more detail would help.

Comment: I'm fixing it up myself.  The original screws didn't go all the way through and were even worse than this one - they fell out.

Comment: That screw looks like a wood screw that was used after the original screw was damaged or lost.

Comment: Yeah.  Was kind of emergency after the old one fell out.  It's holding OK for now but it's not ideal, hence this question. :-)

Comment: If needed you could jam on a small nut onto the end of the screw, but it is single use option, tends to strip the threads and if tighten too much the nut will just fall off/snap the screw end.  Not recommended.

Comment: BTW- That "regular" screw is called a "wood screw". "Machine screws" and "bolts" are also "regular".

Comment: because it's a wood screw it's designed to screw into wood - have you considered using a scrap piece of wood? However I don't think the screw sticks out far enough to have a very good grip on anything you put on this end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can sort-of they're called "*speed nuts*".**
ir's a sort of spring steel contrivance that grasps onto the screw threads and often be pushed on too.

[image]

However I'm not sure that that would be the best solution here.
A ring of 6 or 8 pop-rivets might do a better job.  just in a circle around the base of the moulding at about the same height as the screw.

Apologies for any uncanny valley caused by my poor photo editing skills.

[image]

Comment: Could you give some more detail here, like a link to the speed nuts you're referring to (a search gives me rather a wide variety of things) and maybe an image of what you mean by a "ring of pop-rivets"?

Comment: have done edits.

Comment: Did you?  Can't see any difference.

Comment: aagh! forgot to save :(

Comment: Think OP would want something that covers the end of the screw for safety/prevent blood dripping on stuff, more than a keeper/holder that is not really needed for a screw.  Using pop rivets is a good idea instead of a screw/bolt and nut.

Comment: Do you just mean hammering the rivets in through the metal?  Not sure how doable that would be depending on how hard the metal is.

Comment: @Jez  Do not hammer pop rivets, you squeeze them with a tool called a pop rivet gun, after making the right size hole.  Also known as blind rivets, where you only have access to one side.

Comment: Ah right.  Not really an option here as I can't take the parasol apart, so I can only work with the holes already available.  I guess I'll need to find a bolt that's narrow enough to fit through the existing holes and long enough to get through the pole and out the other side.

Comment: pop rivets fit from the outside, they are what's holding that pulley slot or whatever it is in. see picture.

Comment: @Jez  If space for a drill is the problem, there are right angle attachments that should fit in there.

Comment: Haha, like the image!

Answer (score 7):

No, but you can drill out that hole, or make a new hole and replace the screw with a bolt.

There are different nuts you then use.  Regular nuts, might want two.  locking nuts.  And the one you probably want would be a cap nut, a regular nut with a dome covering the threads.  Length of bolt becomes more important, since cap nuts can only fit on a few threads.

If you want to keep with the screw, you could get a slightly longer screw and use a small block of wood or plastic to screw into and cover the end of the screw.

Comment: Definitely calls for a nut & bolt, not a screw.

Comment: Would you recommend washers on the end of the bolt, between the plastic mould and metal ends of the bolt/nut?

Comment: @Jez  Flat washers will tend to spread the force on the plastic.   Do not really think you need to tighten the nut that much.  Just so it touches/comes close to the plastic.

Comment: Yes, but isn't spreading the force on the plastic good?

Comment: @JezI don't think there's any force to spread on the plastic because you're not torquing that nut down. You just want the nut there to prevent the pieced from coming apart in the up/down direction. They are not spreading apart. A locknut that's not coming off the bolt but on so the bolt can freely spin still solves your problem, right?

Comment: I feel like torquing it down with a washer would help to put less stress on the plastic mould, because otherwise, when the parasol base/pole is turned, all the sideways motion of the parasol canvas turning with it is going to go on the nut pushing against the plastic.  With a torqued couple of washers, the force would be on a wider area.

Comment: @Jez I see your concern. Maybe you could do 2 bolts even in that case. But also I think if the hole is appropriately sized it's not a huge concern.

Comment: If you're chucking the umbrella into a drill, @Jez, then yeah, you'd probably need to worry about the torque. If you're just turning it by hand, there's really not going to be that much torque involved (unless your 6-8 year old kid sees you doing it and decides it's a fun looking play toy). You're really just looking for uplift resistance in wind, and "drop off" resistance when carrying the thing to store it for the winter. Torquing it down isn't really called for here.

Comment: @FreeMan Dunno about that.  I tend to move it by "walking it along" which involves regularly turning it side to side, and already I can see it's widened the hole in the plastic some.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a Heath Robinson bit of work, with the screw point sticking out to catch someone's hand. It needs taking out, and the hole opening up to take a standard bolt or setscrew long enough to go through and take a nut, preferrably self-locking - on the other side. A 6mm or 8mm bolt will suffice, and if it's too long, you could always saw off the part that protrudes beyond the outside of the nut.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the wood screw with a couple of sheet metal screws ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09B6SKCQS)). They will need to be of a diameter to fit firmly into the existing holes in the metal pole. They don't need to be very long as they are fastening the plastic fixture to the adjacent side of the metal pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Place a blob of epoxy putty over the sharp point.